# use database in html5 cross platform application using javascript

Tags: javascript, database, html, cross-platform

How can I use **local database** in my html5,css and java script
cross platform mobile app.I use Intel xdk to build application

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 Local Storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp